# How to select particular area in canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am new to canvas, I have an image myimg.jpg, I have converted this image into canvas and i am trying to apply some pattern image for heel.

I am not able to do it. Here is my screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7APVy.png]

How can I get it done.

```html
<div id="myId">
  <canvas id="canvaswrapper" width="660" height="540"></canvas>
</div>
```

```js
 function drawImage(){
    var ctx = $("canvas")[0].getContext("2d"),
        img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500, 500);
      ctx.beginPath();
      var img2= new Image();
      var w;
      var h;
      img2.src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e555bd971bc2f4910893cd5b785c30ff?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG";
      var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img2, "repeat");
      ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
      ctx.arc(300,305,50,0,2*Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
   };
   img.src = "myimg.jpg"; 
 }
 drawImage();
```

Comment: **vote to reopen**, the only thing that was _unclear_ to me was how to achieve the same thing as Op, and thanks to accepted answer that is now _clear_ ... but now it's _unclear_ to me why this was closed (checked edits; sure K3N did some tidy up, but good question and quality answer, worthy of reopening IMO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the area you want to fill using an image mask that fits on top of your image - this step is something for Photoshop/GIMP.

For example, having your shoe as-is:

[image: shoe]

Create a mask for it leaving the heal in the original position (it makes it easier to draw it back in - you can always crop it and draw it using an offset instead). **Important:** background must be transparent:

[image: mask]

**Then super-impose the pattern using these steps:**

1. Load the pattern and define is as a fill-pattern
2. Draw the *mask* into the empty canvas
3. Optional step: Adjust transformations if needed (translate, scale)
4. Choose composite mode "source-atop"
5. Fill the canvas
6. Choose composite mode "destination-atop"
7. Draw the main image on top (which will show behind the mask/pattern)
8. Optional step: draw in original mask image using blending mode "multiply" to add shadow and highlights (does not work in IE). This will help creating an illusion of depth. For IE, drawing it on top using a reduced alpha or a separate image only containing shadows etc. can be an option

**Result**

[image: result]

## Example

```js
var iShoe = new Image, iMask = new Image, iPatt = new Image, count = 3;
iShoe.onload = iMask.onload = iPatt.onload = loader;
iShoe.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqL1C.png";
iMask.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5XWN.png";
iPatt.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEQ10.png";

function loader() {
  if (--count) return;  // wait until all images has loaded

  var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
      pattern = ctx.createPattern(iPatt, "repeat");

  // draw in mask
  ctx.drawImage(iMask, 0, 0);
  
  // change comp mode
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
  
  // fill mask
  ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5);                 // scale: 0.5
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;             // remember to double the area to fill:
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width*2, ctx.canvas.height*2);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);       // reset transform
  
  // draw shoe behind mask
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
  ctx.drawImage(iShoe, 0, 0);
  
  // to make it more realistic, add mask in blend mode (does not work in IE):
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
  if (ctx.globalCompositeOperation === "multiply") {
    ctx.drawImage(iMask, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas width=281 height=340></canvas>
```

Comment: can we write hover effect for the heel ?

Comment: @dilliy yes, but that is out-of-scope for this question.

Comment: but if i apply some color image shadow is missing on the heel

Comment: @dilliy You have to decide which steps to involve, alternatively create different masks/parts you can use with those images. The (working) solution provided here is based on the image provided in the question.